# How to use SpEL ternary operator on application properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-el, application.properties

I wanted to use a ternary operator with SpEL on application.properties. Something like this:

```
profile: ${spring.profiles.active} == 'dev' ? qa : ${spring.profiles.active}
```

How can I do something like this? Is there another alternative?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you have is correct at least without knowing more information. The ternary operator is correct as long as `${spring.profiles.active}` is a String to compare to 'dev'. You may be able to do something as follows

```java
@Value("#${spring.profiles.active} == 'dev' ? qa : ${spring.profiles.active}")
private String activeProfile;
```

Then you can use activeProfile where you need it